# Insert latest data into mySQL

Tags: mysql

I having a small app. I want after user access, my app will save log on database. Like this :

```
          uid username2      timelogin
          --------------------
          123 ALex       2017-11-25 17:22:00
          134 Anna       2017-11-25 17:25:00
```

But I got a trouble. My app save all timelogin of user. Like this:

```
      uid username2      timelogin
      --------------------
      123 ALex       2017-11-25 17:22:00
      134 Anna       2017-11-25 17:25:00
      123 Alex       2017-11-25 17:26:00
      134 Anna       2017-11-25 17:27:00
```

I want my app only save last time of each username. Like this:

```
      uid username2      timelogin
      --------------------
      123 Alex       2017-11-25 17:26:00
      134 Anna       2017-11-25 17:27:00
```

Please help me fix. This is my MYSQL query.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO log (uid, username2, timelogin)
  VALUES ('$id[1]', '$user[2]', FROM_UNIXTIME($t))";

  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
  } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
  }
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in this

Comment: yes, but it save all user's timelogin. I want update newest timelogin in MySQL. Ex

`123 Alex       2017-11-25 17:22:00` replace by `123 ALex       2017-11-25 17:26:00`

Comment: Maybe see insert update on duplicate key

Comment: if you do not want duplicates, you need to check if entry is already present in database in which case you need to update just the timelogin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REPLACE works exactly like INSERT , except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted. See Section 13.2.5, “INSERT Syntax”. REPLACE is a MySQL extension to the SQL standard.

if uid ,username is primay key.

REPLACE INTO log (uid, username2, timelogin)
  VALUES ('$id[1]', '$user[2]', FROM_UNIXTIME($t))"